# Cloud storage desktop client with no local copy

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, google-drive, dropbox

Does anyone know a cloud storage desktop client/solution for Windows that does not keep a copy of files locally? I'll just login and access the folder where I can dump files I want to be uploaded on the cloud.

Comment: On a linux machine I do it by using sshfs to a VPS ... there are sshfs implementations for windows and mac, but they are old(er) and may not work well these days.  I think winscp can integrate into Explorer (file manager, not browser) so you can go to sftp://user@host/ and save it as a location/library.

Comment: How about [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/)? Do you looking for free app or paid?

Answer (score 1):

## Google Drive

[*Google Drive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) can be used without installing any software on your local computer. Use most any modern web browser. **Drag-and-drop files from your local file system into the Google Drive browser window** to initiate an upload. No linkage or syncing, so you may delete the original files from your local storage after upload completes.